Is Reverse-engineering also about Anti-reverse-engineering?
I recently asked a question about tools helping me to produce an obfuscation on a binary and I have been a bit surprised to see that people were reluctant to answer such a question just because it is about making obfuscation (and not working around it).
For me, deofuscation is also about knowing perfectly the techniques to obfuscate and practicing it. I cannot help but remind the Sun-tzu says: "Know your ennemy!".
So, I would like to know if it is okay to ask question about the way to produce obfuscation and anti-reverse techniques here, or not ?

We've already raised this point: Are questions about trying to make reverse engineering harder appropriate?

Ooops, sorry. The title of the other question did not catch my eyes at first.
